# Create a submit form button which reacts to custom captcha/code field

Tags: php, html

I have the following form

```
<form action="/wp-content/themes/wallstreet/welcome.php" method="post" class="basic-grey">
<h1>Form 
    <span>Please fill all the texts in the fields.</span>
</h1>
<label>
    <span>Your Nickname* :</span>
    <input id="name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="It will appear " />
</label>

<label>
    <span>Your Email* :</span>
    <input id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Valid Email Address" />
</label>

<label>
    <span>Message* :</span>
    <textarea id="messagebook" name="messagebook" placeholder="The text that will appear "></textarea>
</label> 
 <label>
    <span>Code* :</span>
    <input id="code" type="text" name="email" placeholder="The Code That we sent to your email" />
</label>    
 <label>
    <span>&nbsp;</span> 
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Send" /> 
</label>
```

As you can see, it works with a PHP which submits the form to a txt file.

```
    <?php
   $var = $_POST['messagebook'];
    file_put_contents("/var/www/wordpress/wp-content/themes/wallstreet/data.txt", $var . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
    exit();
?>
```

Well, my intention is to store a TXT file which will store 1000 unique codes, like

> AD23A ASSD5 FJLQQ AS223 AS544 ... (Etcetera)

The txt format will be the same as above.

Well so, i want to do something with this pice of code

```
 <label>
    <span>&nbsp;</span> 
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Send" /> 
</label>
```

so the submit button only should work when the code in the field coincides with a code in my .txt file.